# Уменьшение объема Git репозитория

Tags: git, bitbucket

У меня есть самодельная система автобэкапа баз данных, работающая через гит. Храню бэкапы на битбакете, и очевидно, что репозиторий растет, и место на битбакете не резиновое. Собственно, в этом и проблема - нужен метод уменьшения объема репозитория (через баш, чтобы он мог выполняться автоматически раз в условный месяц). Как это делать - не представляю, нужны идеи.

Comment: Если старые версии больше не нужны - грохните репу целиком или перепишите с --force.

Comment: А если новые бэкапы сохранять в новые ветви, а потом убивать старые ветви?

Comment: Насчет переписи не совсем понял. В текущем репозитории писать git init --force, или как? Насчет ветвей - маловероятно. Система должна работать автономно

Comment: да и разработчики программы не представляют, как «**ещё** уменьшить размер хранилища». с сохранением истории, считайте, никак. а без сохранения, конечно, [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41953300/4827341).

Comment: *нужны идеи* — пожалуйста: для хранения бэкапов используйте не программу *git*, а написанные специально для **этой** цели программы. тысячи их. ну, например, [borg](https://github.com/borgbackup/borg)